# Turn off file change monitoring Google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I have an application hosted on GAE where I am creating files within directories which will then get passed to the user. By creating files I mean they are text or image files stored in the working directory or in some sub-directory. However when I create the file to be modified Google app engine recognizes that there was a file changed and will not proceed any further. Is there a way to turn off file change detection completely in my application?

```
INFO     2016-08-18 05:47:39,456 module.py:788] default: "POST /GatherContent HTTP/1.1" 500 2188
INFO     2016-08-18 05:47:40,467 module.py:402] [default] Detected file changes:
```

Comment: How are you creating/modifying the files? And what does "Google app engine recognizes that there was a file changed and will not proceed any further" mean exactly?

Comment: @DanCornilescu updated my question.

Comment: You mean files created somewhere in your application directory and messages coming from your local *development* server, right?

Comment: @DanCornilescu Yes locally, I deployed my app and I am getting the same errors as well.

Comment: It's normal for the dev server to watch for changes in the app files and update its behaviour accordingly, but that doesn't stop its operation (at least on the linux SDK). Once deployed it's not possible to change the app files except via another deployment. So something else is going on in your app - potentially related to the 500 error in your POST request. But without the code there's nothing much I can say.

Comment: @DanCornilescu I can run locally w/o google app engine just fine using the built in language serve mux.

Comment: you know that you won't be able to modify files on the filesystem when the app is deployed right? it then becomes read-only.

Answer (score 0):

The preferred way to store files in GAE is using the [blobstorage](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/) or [cloud storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/). So my guess would be no, it is not possible to turn off.

Comment: Blobstore is soon to be deprecated, and datastore is not for files. I assume you meant Cloud Storage.